# how can I get a layout from another package to be set as activity's view?

Tags: android, android-layout

I know I can get a layout from another package using:

```
    PackageManager.getResourcesForApplication().getLayout();
```

But it returns an XmlResourceParser and I couldn't find a way to use it for setting an Activity's view. There's no such a thing as Activity.setView(XmlResourceParser) or something like that.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer:

```
    View view = LayoutInflater.inflate(XmlResourceParser);
```

That's all!